# How to hide the element A and display the element B when the element C is greater than the element D? And vice versa?

Tags: webforms

I am trying to implement conditional states for the webform I designed through Drupal 9 UI. For the conditional states:

1. I want to display **Total Due Accounting element** (and hide **Total Reimbursement**) when the **Advance Total** (a hidden element that is sum of **New Advance** and **Carry-over amount** elements) is greater than **Item Total** element;
2. Display **Total Reimbursement** element (and hide **Total Due Accounting**) when the **Advance Total** element is less than or equal to **Item Total**.

I have attached two screenshots for both conditions I have created.

When I tested with **Advance Total** less than **Item Total**, only **Total Reimbursement** element is displayed with negative number, which is not what I wanted. May I seek for a help to improve my conditions?

Thank you

[image]

[image]

P.S. Here is my code for **Total Reimbursement** element

```
total_reimbursement:
  '#type': webform_table
  '#title': 'Total Reimbursement'
  '#format': details
  total_reimbursement_01:
    '#type': table_row
    '#title': 'Total Reimbursement (1)'
    total_reimbursement_01_new_advance_:
      '#type': number
      '#title': 'New Advance:'
      '#field_prefix': $
      '#min': 0.01
      '#step': 0.01
    total_reimbursement_01_carry_over_amount_:
      '#type': number
      '#title': 'Carry-over amount:'
      '#field_prefix': $
      '#min': 0.01
      '#step': 0.01
    total_reimbursement_01_expense_items_:
      '#type': computed_twig
      '#title': 'Expense Items:'
      '#template': |-
        {% set unit_total = 0 %}
        {% set final_miles = 0 %}
        {% set mileage_total = 0 %}
        {% for cost in data.expense_items %}
                {% set unit_total = unit_total + (cost.amount)|round(2, 'ceil') %}    
        {% endfor %}        

        {% for mile in data.mileage_count %}
                {% set initial = mile.initial_od|round(2, 'ceil') %}
                {% set final = mile.final_od|round(2, 'ceil')%}
                {% set final_miles = final_miles + (final - initial)|round(2, 'ceil') %}
                {% set mileage_total = mileage_total + (final_miles * 0.585)|round(2, 'ceil') %}
        {% endfor %}


                {% set total_cost = (unit_total + mileage_total)|round(2, 'ceil')%}
        {{ "$ " ~ total_cost|number_format(2,'.',',') }}
      '#store': true
      '#ajax': true
total_reimbursement_01_total_reimbursement_:
  '#type': computed_twig
  '#title': 'Total Reimbursement:'
  '#states':
    invisible-slide:
      - ':input[name="total_reimbursement_01_total_reimbursement_"]':
          value:
            less_equal: '0'
      - or
      - ':input[name="total_due_accounting"]':
          value:
            less: '0'
  '#states_clear': false
  '#template': |-
    {% set unit_total = 0 %}
    {% set final_miles = 0 %}
    {% set mileage_total = 0 %}

    {% set new_advance = 0 + (data.total_reimbursement_01_new_advance_)|round(2, 'ceil') %}
    {% set carry_over = 0 + (data.total_reimbursement_01_carry_over_amount_)|round(2, 'ceil') %}
    {% set advance_total = 0 + (new_advance + carry_over)|round(2, 'ceil') %}

    {% for cost in data.expense_items %}
            {% set unit_total = unit_total + (cost.amount)|round(2, 'ceil') %}    
    {% endfor %}        

    {% for mile in data.mileage_count %}
            {% set initial = mile.initial_od|round(2, 'ceil') %}
            {% set final = mile.final_od|round(2, 'ceil')%}
            {% set final_miles = final_miles + (final - initial)|round(2, 'ceil') %}
            {% set mileage_total = mileage_total + (final_miles * 0.585)|round(2, 'ceil') %}
    {% endfor %}

            {% set total_cost = (unit_total + mileage_total)|round(2, 'ceil')%}
            {% set total_reimbursement = (total_cost - advance_total)|round(2, 'ceil') %}
    {{ "$ " ~ total_reimbursement|number_format(2,'.',',') }}
  '#store': true
  '#ajax': true
```

And here is for **Total Accounting Due** element:

```
total_due_accounting:
  '#type': computed_twig
  '#title': 'Total Due Accounting:'
  '#states':
    invisible-slide:
      - ':input[name="total_due_accounting"]':
          value:
            less: '0'
      - or
      - ':input[name="total_reimbursement_01_total_reimbursement_"]':
          value:
            less_equal: '0'
  '#states_clear': false
  '#template': |-
    {% set unit_total = 0 %}
    {% set final_miles = 0 %}
    {% set mileage_total = 0 %}

    {% set new_advance = 0 + (data.total_reimbursement_01_new_advance_)|round(2, 'ceil') %}
    {% set carry_over = 0 + (data.total_reimbursement_01_carry_over_amount_)|round(2, 'ceil') %}
    {% set advance_total = 0 + (new_advance + carry_over)|round(2, 'ceil') %}

    {% for cost in data.expense_items %}
            {% set unit_total = unit_total + (cost.amount)|round(2, 'ceil') %}    
    {% endfor %}        

    {% for mile in data.mileage_count %}
            {% set initial = mile.initial_od|round(2, 'ceil') %}
            {% set final = mile.final_od|round(2, 'ceil')%}
            {% set final_miles = final_miles + (final - initial)|round(2, 'ceil') %}
            {% set mileage_total = mileage_total + (final_miles * 0.585)|round(2, 'ceil') %}
    {% endfor %}

            {% set total_cost = (unit_total + mileage_total)|round(2, 'ceil')%}
            {% set total_reimbursement = (advance_total - total_cost)|round(2, 'ceil') %}
    {{ "$ " ~ total_reimbursement|number_format(2,'.',',') }}
  '#store': true
  '#ajax': true
```

Comment: Can you create a gist or a share a copy of your current webform build?

Comment: are you talking about the code for my computed twigs?

Comment: Go to the "Build" tab of your webform, then click "Source"

Comment: Got it, please see the attached code for both elements.